# jquery plugin to add a div as a mask

Tags: jquery

from 2 month i saw in the intrnet
js code when click submit button it add a hight z-index div as a mask in the form and there is img loading in the center of that div
where i can find that code agian

Comment: This is terribly unclear, but maybe you mean JCrop: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking at code to display a popup. There are libraries that do that, but it is not too difficult to do your self. Here is an example of how you might achieve this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/r77K8/5/

Hope that gets you started.

Bop

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [Fancybox?](http://fancybox.net/)